# Swift 2.1 - Making dynamic buttons with width relative to text length

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to make buttons programmatically based on the number of fetched values and each button needs to have width that is relative to their text length.
My current implementation has a fixed width with X position that also increments in fixed length.

What is the process of achieving this so I can have buttons like attached screenshot?

```
for var i = 0; i < self.category.count; i++ {
    let frame1 = CGRect(x: 0 + (i * 45), y: 20, width: 80, height: 40 )
    let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
    button.setTitle("\(category[i].name!)", forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.categoryScrollView.addSubview(button) 
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use layout constraints rather than setting the frame, the button size will automatically adjust, and just an FYI: that type of for loop is deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you set text on button, use

```
button.sizeToFit()
```

then read the width of the button and add an appropriate number to it (this number will be same for all buttons regardless of the text length and will give you desired results.

Alternatively, you can add padding to button; in which case you only need to do the first step.

Comment: Thanks. How can I read the width of a button? I think the best way is to use `button.sizeToFit()` and add padding. Would you be able to show some code that adds padding? And I'm not sure if CGRect is still necessary. And making them spread horizontally (x position) with consistent margin still remains a question.

Comment: for padding try `button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)`, Play with the number to get desired results. You still need to define a frame/cgrect in beginning as you are now, then later code will amend it properly.

Comment: contentEdgeInsets will add padding within the width of a button which makes all button text become `...` or not display any text. It looks like there is no Outset method. Still a long way to get the desirable outcome.
And how cam I get the width of a button after I do `sizeToFit()`?

Comment: `Button.frame.size.width` will give you width. There is `Button.titleEdgeInsets` too.